# What is the best practice of updating child relationship rows of a state?

Tags: corda

hope you all well, am working on updating a Linear persistent Corda state that has some entity relationships attached to it.

But am getting an issue of Hibernate "Unique index or primary key violation" on persisting updated state details in my update Flow.

-> Am wondering if I should create different entity relationships table IDs for rows of the new updated state and children rows information.

-> OR If you can give me the best practice of updating child contract state relations table rows of a state.

Any help will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#schemas.
The Corda Site Provides a suitable example to  achieve you requirement.
In case this doesn't solve your query a code snippet of your Schema representation would help .